# Getting ModuleNotFoundError after the installation of pyaudio

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook for a voice assistant and it is showing that the pyaudio file has been downloaded succesfully in Anaconda Prompt. But when I import it using

```
import pyaudio
```

I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

I have tried many installation methods like:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

and :

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```

and after installation I am not able to access it. I have not downloaded portaudio as I am getting the same error with it

Comment: Are you sure that you are using environment in which you have installed it?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments find out which conda environment you are using with jupyter

If you don't know which environemt you are using, go ahead like this

1. get list of environments you have in cmd-line

```
conda env list
```

2. activate environment from command line (windows) or shell (linux/mac)
   https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

if you are using anaconda version >= 4.6

```
conda activate <env-name>
```

commonly people are using "base" environment for the start

```
conda activate base
```

3. list all packages installed (check if its available)

```
conda list
```

4. pip install if not available

```
pip install pyaudio
```

5. start jupyter notebook from activated environment. Type in cmd-line

```
jupyter notebook
```